# Multiple lines in a single column for creating a VIEW

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this kind of data :

```
Client Number        Name of the direction
11                   John
11                   JIM
11                   Isabel
12                   Paul
12                   Batman
13                   Flash
```

I want to create a view like this :

```
CLIENT NUMBER        NAMES
11                   John, Jim, Isabel
12                   Paul, Batman
13                   Flash
```

I can have one or several names for the same client number.

How can I create a View with the different names in the same column ?

I already made a view but I Can't figure how to concat the names ?

Comment: Hint:  `string_agg()`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use GROUP BY to concatenate strings in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273238/how-to-use-group-by-to-concatenate-strings-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `STRING_AGG()`.

```
CREATE VIEW your_view_name AS  -- replace your view name
SELECT [Client Number],STRING_AGG([Name of the direction],', ') AS [NAME] FROM your_table_name -- replace you table name
GROUP BY [Client Number]
```

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server versions prior to 2017, you could also use `FOR XML PATH`.

```
CREATE VIEW view_name AS
SELECT DISTINCT T2.clientNumber, 
    SUBSTRING(
        (
            SELECT ','+ T1.Names  AS [text()]
            FROM table_Name T1
            WHERE T1.clientNumber = T2.clientNumber
            ORDER BY T1.clientNumber
            FOR XML PATH ('')
        ), 2, 1000) AS [NameList]
FROM table_Name T2
```